# jquery mobile form submit. Simple form that takes user to page on form submit

Tags: forms, jquery-mobile

I'm struggling with a form submit in jquery mobile and the api doesn't show any useful examples.

Here is my html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="test" data-id="test">
                <div data-role="content">
                    <form id="form1">
                        <div id="titleDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">  
                            <label id="titlelabel" for="title">Title *</label>  
                            <select id="title" name="title">  
                            <option value="null">Please select a title</option>  
                            <option value="mr">Mr</option>  
                            <option value="miss">Miss</option>  
                            <option value="mrs">Mrs</option>  
                            <option value="ms">Ms</option>  
                            <option value="dr">Dr</option>  
                            </select>  
                        </div> 
                        <div id="submitDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">    
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" data-inline="true"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>  
            </div> 
        </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="test" data-id="test">
        <p>form confirmation page</p>
    </div>
```

and here is my javascript:

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui) {

$('#form1').submit(function() {
     alert('test');
     // Submit the form
     //        $.post("/forms/requestProcessor.php", form1Var.serialize(), function(data){
     //        });   

    $.mobile.changePage($("#test"), "slideUp");
    return false;
});           
});
```

On submit, I want it to show an alert then take the user to a page. At the moment, that code shows the alert 3 times the does nothing. Any ideas what is wrong with it?

Comment: Following this did the trick: http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2011/06/29/creating-a-contact-form-in-jquery-mobile-and-php/

Comment: The link has an exploit. Beware.

Answer (score 0):

A problem is that you're re-using the `test` id.  Give the second page a different id and `changePage` to that id will work.  Also it would be better to omit the `pageshow` or restrict it to `#test` rather than all the divs in your page.